# why doesn't rackstore see the path to reach the palletrack?

Tags: anylogic

I don't know why the resources don't follow the path in order to arrive the pallet rack. I thought it was because of the path (maybe not linked) but with a moveto block the problem disappears.What's the reason?
All the paths are bidirectional.
[image: path]

[image: flowchart]

Comment: this feature normally works... it's possible that your box is defined in agent that is different from where the resources live, so you need to be careful

Comment: both box and resource are "agent type" and both queue of rackstore and resources are placed in the same node.

Comment: all resources are agent type, and rackstores are not placed in any node... so your sentence doesn't give any useful information... also you didn't seem to have checked the possible error i mentioned you might have

Comment: I'm sorry, i intended that both the resources and box are placed in the same node. I didn't check the possible error because i didn't get it . Could you explain  me?thanks for the patience .

Comment: share the model

Comment: here: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AhfvS-jv8ukShIRtDNG-DUolG-Z6Ow?e=FCYsbb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem that you have is the issue of teleportation... you move your boxes teleporting them from one node to the next by using the agent location parameter of the rackstore... This has the effect that the agents do not belong to the network as you expect.

instead you need to use a moveTo block instead as you see in the following image
[image: moveTo]

Notice that I removed the agent location from the rackStore and also in the moveTo block i use JumpTo option instead of moveTo so you maintain the teleportation as you did...

Anyways, teleporting is not very good